# Local save blob file in Laravel / php (from JS/axios)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, blob

I would like to save a blob (from JS) to a file (through a php controller).

I have tried almost everything, I guess, with no success. Here is what I get: I don't manage to get the content of the file itself. I guess I am not far but I am missing something.

[image]

and here is everything I tried

```
public function uploadsimplefile(Request $request){
    $blob = $request->blob;
    $filename = $request->name;

    $path ="./gpx/" . $filename;

    //test 1
    file_put_contents(
        $path,
        base64_decode($blob)
    );

    //test 2
    file_put_contents(
        "./gpx/test2.jpg",
        $blob
    );

    //test 3
    $content = file_get_contents($blob); // URL of your blob object
    file_put_contents("./gpx/test3.jpg", $content);

    //test 4
    $ch = curl_init($blob);
    $fp = fopen("./gpx/test4.jpg", 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    //test 5
    $upload_dir = "./gpx/";
    $img = $blob;
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = $upload_dir .  "test5.jpg";
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';

}
```